# Passing the response of http post1 to another and getting response back from post2 in Angular

Tags: angular, promise, observable, es6-promise

I'm trying to post a request for authorizing a user. After logging in I want to send another http.post to set some information about that user. So far my login call works :
(Angular) auth_service.ts :

```
Login() {
    let promiseResult : any;
    this.http.post<any>('/auth/Login', this.auth_payload).toPromise().then(data => {
      promiseResult = data;
      console.log("Login call" ,promiseResult)
      return promiseResult

    });
```

auth_component.ts :

```
 onSubmit(form : NgForm){
    this.authService.Login()
  }
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to make the second post request work. I want to press a button on the HTML upon which the response from the second call will be retrieved. How should I make a "connection" between these two requests?

I've read about Promises and Observables but I don't get how do I use them in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
YourMethod(): Observable < any > {
  let firstResult;
  let secondResult;

  return http.get('////').pipe(
    switchMap(res1 =>  this.http.post<any>('/auth/Login', this.auth_payload).pipe(
      map(res2 => [res1, res2])
    ))
  );
}

CallingMethod() {
  this.YourMethod().subscribe(([firstResult, secondResult]) => {
    /// Some logic
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a call to your second endpoint in your promise callback:

```
Login() {
    let promiseResult : any;
    this.http.post<any>('/auth/Login', this.auth_payload).toPromise().then(data => 
    {
      promiseResult = data;
      console.log("Login call" ,promiseResult)
      this.setInformation(data)
      return promiseResult

    });

setInformation(userData) {
    let promiseResult : any;
    this.http.post<any>('/information/endPoint', userData).toPromise().then(data => {
      promiseResult = data;
      console.log("set Information call" ,promiseResult)
      return promiseResult

    });
```

However I am not sure that this is conceptually correct if the login and the set information are on the same server you can manage this directly in your server application

Comment: By server application do you mean the backend? (I'm a beginner bear with me please). I have to send a request from the front end to the server and get a response from there

Answer (score 1):

Whatever your return from a `then` is going to be passed to the next one, so you can just do that:

```
this.http.post<any>('/auth/Login', this.auth_payload)
    .toPromise()
    .then(data => this.doSomethingMore(data))
    .then(moreData => this.doSomethingElse(moreData));
```

You can shorten `.then(data => this.doSomethingMore(data))` with `.then(this.doSomethingMore)` but for clarity sake, I didn't do it.

If `doSomethingMore` return a Promise then it will be executed and its result passed to the next `then`.

Same with Observable:

```
this.http.post<any>('/auth/Login', this.auth_payload)
    .pipe(
        switchMap(data => this.doSomethingMore(data)),
        switchMap(moreData => this.doSomethingElse(moreData)),
    );
```